# Generating dropdown values based on value of another dropdown in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, enums, html-select

So basically, what I'm trying to do is show the value of status dropdown as [initial, started completed] when bug_type dropdown's value is bug, otherwise status dropdown should show [initial, started, resolved]

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.select :bug_type, options_for_select([['Bug', 'bug'], ['Feature', 'feature']]) %> <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <% if @bug.bug_type == 'bug'%>
      <%= form.select :status, options_for_select([['Initial', 'initial'], ['Started', 'started'], ['Completed', 'completed']]) %> <br>
    <% else %>
      <%= form.select :status, options_for_select([['Initial', 'initial'], ['Started', 'started'], ['Resolved', 'resolved']]) %> <br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far, I tried doing this but it doesn't work.
Also, I've used enums for bug_type and status. Please help me, if there's another approach to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways for your requirement. One is client side you can change the dropdown value or you can send one server side request and render your required options.

For client side you can do like this:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.select :bug_type, options_for_select([["Bug", "bug"], ["Feature", "feature"]]) %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <% if @bug.bug_type == "bug" %>
      <%= form.select :status, options_for_select([["Initial", "initial"], ["Started", "started"], ["Completed", "completed"]]) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= form.select :status, options_for_select([["Initial", "initial"], ["Started", "started"], ["Resolved", "resolved"]]) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Please change selector accoding to your DOM.
  // This is bug type select dropdown
  $('#bug_type_select').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $('#bug_type option:selected').val();
    var bugOptions = {
      'initial': 'Initial',
      'started': 'Started',
      'completed': 'Completed'
    }

    var featureOptions = {
      'initial': 'Initial',
      'started': 'Started',
      'resolved': 'Resolved'
    }

    // Please change selector accoding to your DOM.
    // This is status select dropdown
    var $mySelect = $('#mySelect');
    $mySelect.empty();

    if (selectedValue === 'bug') {
      $.each(bugOptions, function(key, value) {
        var $option = $('<option/>', {
          value: key,
          text: value
        });

        $mySelect.append($option);
      });
    } else {
      $.each(featureOptions, function(key, value) {
        var $option = $('<option/>', {
          value: key,
          text: value
        });

        $mySelect.append($option);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```